# Is there a non-contractible Simplicial Complex with Euler Characteristic 1?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It seems apparent that all contractible simplicial complexes have Euler characteristic of $\chi=1$.  Are there any non-contractible (path-connected) simplicial complexes with Euler characteristic $\chi=1$?

Comment: Apparently every *simply connected* simplicial or CW-complexe of dimension 2 and of Euler characteristic 1 is contractible.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, many.  For a concrete example, how about an octahedron with an edge running through the middle?

It's worth noting that such a complex must necessarily have dimension at least 2, since a path connected 0-complex is just a point, and a noncontractible path-connected 1-complex is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circles, which has nonpositive Euler characteristic.