# Non-contractible simplicial complex and Euler characteristic 1

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

It is a specialisation of [Is there a non-contractible Simplicial Complex with Euler Characteristic 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58148/84284)

Here is a list of non-contractible simplicial complex with Euler characteristic $1$:

- *non-homogeneous*: an octahedron with an edge running through the middle (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58150/84284))
- *non-oriented*: triangulation of the real projective plane (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2831))
- *non-connected*: triangulation of the disjoint union of a disk and a torus

**Question**: Is there a non-contractible homogeneous oriented connected simplicial complex with Euler Characteristic $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(S^1 \times S^3) \#\Bbb CP^2$

Comment: Do you believe that $4$ is the smallest real dimension for a boundaryless example?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux You mean $4$?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux For closed oriented manifolds at least, 4 is the minimum as the Euler characteristic of any closed oriented surface is $2-2g$ and the Euler characteristic of any closed odd dimensional manifold is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a $2$-disk with two smaller open $2$-disks removed.

Then $\chi(X)=-1$ and therefore $\chi (X\times X)=(-1)^2 =1$.

Right?

Comment: Is that homoegeous? It has non-empty boundary, so I don't think so.

Comment: In my understanding, homogeneous means that the local dimension is the same everywhere, but does allow for boundary.

Comment: I admit that @PVAL-inactive's answer is definitely more beautiful though.

Comment: I thought homogenous meant the automorphism group of $X$ acted transitively on $X$. I.e., for every $x,y \in X$, there exists an automorphism $h \colon X \to X$ such that $h(x) = y$.